# Cut a translucent square in a texture

Tags: opengl, java, libgdx, opengl-es2

How to remove (cut-out) a transparent rectangle in a Texture, so that the hole will be translucent.

On Android I would use the Xfermodes approach:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115732/how-to-use-masks-in-android

But in libgdx I will have to use opengl. So far I almost achieved what I was looking for, by using the the glBlendFunc  From this nice and very helpful [page](http://www.andersriggelsen.dk/glblendfunc.php) I learend that

```
glBlendFunc(GL_ZERO, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

should  solve my problem, but I tried it out, and it did not quite work as expected:

```
batch.end();
batch.begin();

batch.setBlendFunction(GL20.GL_ZERO,
        GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
// Draw the background
super.draw(batch, x, y, width, height);
// draw the foreground
mask.draw(batch, x + innerButtonTable.getX(), y
        + innerButtonTable.getY(), innerButtonTable.getWidth(),
        innerButtonTable.getHeight());
// result = {foreground}*{0,0,0,0} +
// {background}*(1-sourceAlpha)

batch.end();
batch.setBlendFunction(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA,
        GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
batch.begin();
```

It is just making the mask area plain black, whereas I was expecting transparency, any ideas.

This is what I get:

[image: Mask will be drawn black]

This is what I expected:

[image: Mask area should be transparent]

Comment: Is there any particular reason your first 'batch.setBlendFunction()' is inside 'batch.begin(); ... batch.end();' and your second call is outside of the ''batch.begin(); ... batch.end();'?

Comment: Also, to me it looks like the second 'batch.setBlendFunction()'s parameters should be used before drawing the mask (since it mentions the alpha source) rather than after. Maybe try switching the two calls you make.

Comment: thanks for the comment, but it did not help, I updated my code above, maybe I just missunderstood something.

Comment: um this may sound silly, but you are enabling Blend right? batch.glEnable(GL_BLEND);

Comment: I just tried with: Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL20.GL_BLEND);, same same

Comment: cross-site duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15117789/cut-a-translucent-square-in-a-texture

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved my problem by using the stencil buffer:

```
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);
batch.end();
//disable color mask
Gdx.gl.glColorMask(false, false, false, false);
Gdx.gl.glDepthMask(false);
//enable the stencil
Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL20.GL_STENCIL_TEST);
Gdx.gl.glStencilFunc(GL20.GL_ALWAYS, 0x1, 0xffffffff);
Gdx.gl.glStencilOp(GL_REPLACE, GL_REPLACE, GL_REPLACE);

batch.begin();
//draw the mask
mask.draw(batch, x + innerButtonTable.getX(), y
        + innerButtonTable.getY(), innerButtonTable.getWidth(),
        innerButtonTable.getHeight());

batch.end();
batch.begin();

//enable color mask 
Gdx.gl.glColorMask(true, true, true, true);
Gdx.gl.glDepthMask(true);
//just draw where outside of the mask
Gdx.gl.glStencilFunc(GL_NOTEQUAL, 0x1, 0xffffffff);
Gdx.gl.glStencilOp(GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP);
//draw the destination texture
super.draw(batch, x, y, width, height);
batch.end();
//disable the stencil
Gdx.gl.glDisable(GL20.GL_STENCIL_TEST);
```